# how to applied < operator between string parameters in linq c#

Tags: c#, linq, operator-keyword

I have a LINQ c# in which I have the following condition in where clause where I have to compare to fields one is a string and other is Int but   **`<`** operator is not applicable between these conditions

(Note: I just want to apply '<' operator No change of datatype of any field  is req)

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchExpression))
      _allData = _allData.Where(a => (a.VM_VERIFIED) < (a.VT_FINALAPP_LVL));

    _allData = _allData.AsQueryable().where(SearchExpression, objList);

    ds.Tables.Add(Utilities.LinqToDataTable(_allData, "GL_CHEQUES"));

   _Envelope.SetMaster(ds);
```

Comment: When is a string less than a decimal?

Comment: Is `"Hello"` less or more than `2.45`? By what rules do you determine that?

Comment: both fields have data in numbers

Comment: by changing datatype it gives no data on the other hand that query on oracle have data

Comment: KANWAL _"both fields have data in numbers"_ - but `"2.45"` is not a number, it's a string. You know it's a string representation of a number, but the compiler can't make that decision (especially since it won't have the data until runtime). It sounds like your database field type is wrong, to be honest.

Comment: One field (the one of type `decimal`) contains data, that is known to represent a number with clearly defined rules. The other one (of type `string`) _might_ contain characters, that _look_ like digits, but it's up to interpretation (parsing), to know, what number is meant. Kind of like the string `"hundred"` needs to be "parsed" to know that the number `100` is meant.

Comment: you just suppose both field have data  like(1 to 10 ) but one field is assigned to Number datatype in oracle and other field is assigned to varchar datatype in oracle

Comment: @KANWALSHAHID - _you_ know that. The compiler doesn't. The compiler just sees a field of type string. For all it knows, the field could contain the full text of "war and piece". So you need to tell it to parse the string into a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the string to decimal as such:

```
_allData = _allData.Where(a => Convert.ToDecimal((a.VM_VERIFIED)) < (a.VT_FINALAPP_LVL));
```

Still, not a good practice I´d assume.

Comment: yes i tried this but this conversion gives no data in my linq

Comment: And hope, that the string representation of the decimal value follows the same cultural rules as the current thread. Some cultures (for example "de-DE") use a comma instead of a period as a decimal separator for example. So `2.45` would be represented by the string `"2,45"`. -- better to specify the expected culture explicitly.

Comment: Indeed, Corak. Kanwal would get a FormatException. Best solution is to correct the type on a database level.

Comment: i wish i can :D